# Mongodb authentication error when selecting database from command line

Tags: mongodb, authentication, command-line-interface

I am trying to delete a mongo database inside a shell script. The server requries authentication with a password. When I type the following into the command line:

```sh
mongo -u mun -p 'themongopassword'
```

I am able to connect to the database and then when run the following commands:

```js
use dbname
db.dropDatabase()
```

The database is successfully deleted. However I would like to do the following:

```sh
mongo -u mun -p 'themongopassword' --eval 'db.dropDatabase()' sigma
```

I get the following output:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.6
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/sigma?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-05-06T13:13:53.419+0300 E  QUERY    [js] Error: Authentication failed. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2020-05-06T13:13:53.420+0300 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2020-05-06T13:13:53.420+0300 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

Removing the eval option like so:

```sh
mongo -u mun -p 'themongopassword' sigma
```

also results in an authentication failure with the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this:

```
mongo <dbname> -u mun -p 'themongopassword' --eval "db.dropDatabase()"
```

If you want to get a readable result try this:

```
 mongo <dbname> -u mun -p 'themongopassword' --eval "printjson(db.dropDatabase())"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding option "--authenticationDatabase admin", i.e.:

```
mongo <dbname> -u mun -p 'themongopassword' --authenticationDatabase admin --eval "printjson(db.dropDatabase())"
```